# angular 4 - first load filter is not working

Tags: angular, adal

I have angular 4 application with Azure AD Authentication. After user logged in i am redirecting user to Home component. On Home component i am calling API to get Certain data and load in Grid. I have text box where user can filter the grid data and have written custom PIPE for that. 
Problem : When Home component first loads, Data is coming correctly but filter is not working until i refresh page manually for the first time. 
Below is my Route Configuration.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },    
    { path: 'home', component: HCOHomeComponent,canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandler]},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'hco/:hcoId', component: HCODetailsComponent, canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandler]},
    { path: 'hco/edit/:hcoId', component: HCOEditComponent,canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandler] },
    { path: 'hcoevent/:hcoeventId', component: HCOEventDetailsComponent, canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandler] },
    { path: 'hcoevent/edit/:hcoeventId', component: HCOEventEditComponent, canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandler] },
    { path: 'id_token', component: OAuthCallbackComponent, canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandler] }, 
    { path: 'access_token', component: OAuthCallbackComponent, canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandler] }, 
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{ useHash: true });
```

I have filter like this,

```
 <div  *ngFor="let hco of lstResult | searchFilter: {Name: searchID}">
```

where searchID is my textbox value.

Home component has below code for fetching data from API using service.

```
GetAllHCOs() {
        this.msg = 'Loading...';        
        this.hcoService.get()
            .subscribe((hcos: any) => {
                this.zone.run(() => {
                    this.lstResult = hcos; this.msg = '';
                })
            }, error => this.msg = '');

    }
```

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong here.
And also when i call edit on first load it is not working, i have to refresh page , then everything works properly.

Comment: Did you mean after the users redirecting to the home component and type the filter info in the textbox, the grid doesn't filter as expect?

Comment: Yes. When redirected it does not filter. When i manually refresh the page, then filter starts working.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a demo code sample to help narrow down this issue?